# How to enable duplex printing on HP 7610 with Linux (Ubuntu 13.04)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, printing, duplex, ppd

I have equipped my HP 7610 printer with the duplex extension, but the configuration dialogs of Ubuntu and Kubuntu still have the duplex option greyed out. Even re-installing the printer does not help. It seems the printer doesn't tell the computer that it is capable of duplex printing now, still the same configuration is used.

Is there a way of enabling duplex printing for this model?

Would it help to add somethig to the PPD file? What would this extension look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution by copying parts of my old HP930C ppd-file to the ppd-file of the HP7610.

First I added the following before the line "*OpenUI *InputSlot/Media Source: PickOne":

```
*OpenUI *Duplex/Double-Sided Printing: PickOne
*OrderDependency: 10 AnySetup *Duplex
*DefaultDuplex: DuplexNoTumble
*Duplex DuplexNoTumble/Long Edge (Standard): "<</Duplex true/Tumble false>>setpagedevice"
*Duplex DuplexTumble/Short Edge (Flip): "<</Duplex true/Tumble true>>setpagedevice"
*Duplex None/Off: "<</Duplex false/Tumble false>>setpagedevice"
*CloseUI: *Duplex
```

Then I added the followoing before the line "*DefaultFont: Courier":

```
*OpenGroup: InstallableOptions/Installable Options
*OpenUI *OptionDuplex/Duplexer Installed: Boolean
*OrderDependency: 10 AnySetup *OptionDuplex
*DefaultOptionDuplex: True
*OptionDuplex False/Not Installed: ""
*OptionDuplex True/Installed: ""
*CloseUI: *OptionDuplex
*CloseGroup: InstallableOptions
```

That enabled me to tell the CUPS system that the duplex option is installed and to select duplex printing in applications. Unfortunately, all output came out "short edge/flip". I had to add the following after the line "*RequiresPageRegion All: True" to make CUPS turn one side of the page so that the output now is perfect:

```
*cupsEvenDuplex: True
*cupsBackSide: "Rotated"
*cupsFlipDuplex: True
```

Additionally, I reordered the page size entries to have all relevant ISO-standardized sizes at the top of the list. The [result of the whole process](http://plausibolo.de/sonst/HP-Officejet-7610-series.ppd) can be downloaded.

Comment: I am trying to get my Samsung printer working on a Raspberry Pi. Since the drivers are not supported on the Pi, I set it up as a generic printer and use Samba to connect to it. This works, but duplex is not work even with your changes. Any ideas on a fix?

Answer (score 0):

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/HardwareSupportComponentsPrintersHp Here the list doesn't mentions officially supporting about your printer HP 7610. Which driver did you installed to make it detected by ubuntu.

Thanks & Regards,
Alok Thaker

Comment: http://hplipopensource.com/hplip-web/release_notes.html says:
    HPLIP 3.13.7 - This release has the following changes:
    Added Support for the Following New Printers:

    - HP Deskjet 1010 Printer
    - HP Deskjet 1012 Printer
    - HP ENVY 5530 e-All-in-One Printer
    - HP ENVY 5535 e-All-in-One Printer
    - HP Officejet 7610 Wide Format e-All-in-One Printer
The printer was automatically detected.

Actually, there is no official mentioning of supportig duplex mode.